# How to send SMS via OpenEdge 10.2B

Tags: sms, openedge

I'm a beginner to this language. Please if anyone know a way to send SMS via Openedge 10.2B using a dongal or a modem. please educate me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way I know how to do this would be to write some code in another language to interface with the dongle or the modem and the then call that from within OpenEdge. You can't do it natively.

Comment: Progress supports calling .Net with some limitations (threading related), procedures in dlls and on *ix shared libraries so it's not true that it can't be done natively. Theres also support for calling webservices if thats an option.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would communicate to the SMS provider via some sort of API. Without this information it is not possible to answer your question. Also relevant, do you want to send the SMS's from the client or the server (does that matter)?